# Page rendered differently in Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, css, sass, next.js

In Safari, the personal picture takes up more than its parent container and is not staying within the container. In Firefox, it renders correctly.

I am using React, so that is why my classNames are formatted that way.

```
 <div className="landing">
    <div className="landing-content">
      <div className="portait-container">
        <img src="../static/portrait.jpg" className='portait' />
        <p>Thats Me!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.landing {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10vw 15vw auto 15vw 10vw;
  grid-template-rows: 25vh 75vh;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.landing-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.portait-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
.portait {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try requiring or importing the image first.

```
import portrait from '../static/portrait.jpg';
             OR
var portrait =  require('../static/portrait.jpg') 
<img src={ portrait } className='portait'/>
```

[docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Comment: I am using NextJS, so their procedure is to use the /static folder.

Comment: I seem to be missing something.  In my answer aren't you still requiring or importing from /static?  If the issue is NextJS-specific, adding a NextJS tag might get you a more relevant  answer...

Comment: It throws an error and says I need a loader on trying to import. If I use require it loads but is still having the same issue.

Comment: At risk of wasting your time, I'm curious if changing width & height to 100vw & 100vh would make a difference.

Comment: Changing the root height and width to 100vw vh, worked. I also changed the size of the img to 50vw and it works.

Comment: Glad yo hear.  Enjoy the rest of your weekend.